# how to do string formatting in python for this specific example

Tags: python-3.x, string, formatting, os.system

```
pair = ['BTC/USD', 'ETH/BTC', 'ETH/USD']
time_from = 20200101
time_to = 20200120
```

considering the above list and variables

I want to execute the following cmd using os module.

```
cmd = ("freqtrade download-data -d /home/datarepo -p 'BTC/USD' 'ETH/BTC' 'ETH/USD' -t 1h --timerange 20200101-20200101 --exchange bittrex -vv")
```

When I do string format with `"' '".join` I could able to generate cmd like the below example which is not correct cmd.

```
cmd = ("freqtrade download-data -d /home/datarepo -p "BTC/USD' 'ETH/BTC' 'ETH/USD" -t 1h --timerange '20200101-20200101' --exchange bittrex -vv")
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```py
pair = ['BTC/USD', 'ETH/BTC', 'ABC/DEF']
time_from = 20200101
time_to = 20200120

message = "'" + "' '".join(pair) + "'"

cmd = "freqtrade download-data -d /home/datarepo -p %pair% -t 1h --timerange '%time_to%-%time_from%' --exchange bittrex -vv"

cmd = cmd.replace('%pair%', message).replace('%time_to%', str(time_to)).replace('%time_from%', str(time_from))

print(cmd)
# "freqtrade download-data -d /home/datarepo -p 'BTC/USD' 'ETH/BTC' 'ABC/DEF' -t 1h --timerange '20200120-20200101' --exchange bittrex -vv"
```

Comment: I have updated the details, please have a look. That is what i exactly needed.Thank you

Comment: just updated my answer for the new question

Comment: could you please mark the post as the answer of the question?